# Injecting widgets depending on item selected in drop down

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm wondering how to fill the blank area with widgets that I've pre-defined according to the opencv filter that is selected. I looked at qhide and qshow, but when I have upwards of 12 different filters in the same window, clutter becomes a problem.

Any suggestions?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GffUE.jpg

Comment: Are your widgets created using designer or are they created in c++ code?

Comment: qtcreator so i guess i'm using qtdesigner by default?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I think is use [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) class. You can create several pages with different widgets on it and add to stack.

```
stack->addWidget(widget);
```

Then when you select some value at combobox you can show appropriated page inside stack widget.

```
stack->setCurrentIndex(index);
```

Comment: Right now I'm just drag and dropping my buttons into a .ui file, with QStackedWidget I would have to write this out inside the Window.cpp file myself?

Comment: No, you can create as mani UI files with designer as you need. Then create widgets from code and install this UI files on it.

Comment: I've created 2 pages to test from, how would I have them be displayed through the dropdown menu? I'm in my opencv_Window.cpp file and I have the following 

void opencv_Window::on_FilterList_activated(const QString &arg1)
{
    currentFilter = arg1.toStdString();

    if(currentFilter == "Division of Gaussian Saliency"){ /*Code here */  ;}

}

Comment: In this method you only need select widget at stack like I have show at my answer. But some where else (at constructor for instance) you shoyld populate stack with your pages. Create widgets, setup UI on it and add them to stack.

Comment: Just read link with documentation from my answer. The are examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a layout at the suitable place in your main-window and add or remove widgets based on requirement.

You can create all the widget instances in the constructor if you want them at all times to sync things in background. If that's not required, you can create the instances when required and delete them when not.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    widget1 = new MyWidget1;
    widget2 = new MyWidget2;
    widget3 = new MyWidget3;

    // myWidgetlayout could be a QHBoxLayout or a QVBoxLayout
    ui->myWidgetlayout->addWidget(widget1);

    .... //Continue with rest of the things
}
```

Whenever you want to change the widget, you can  execute something like:

```
ui->myWidgetlayout->removeWidget(widget1);
ui->myWidgetlayout->addWidget(widget2);
```

Comment: Hmm... I think I follow you, I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Also, the problem of clutter seems to be nagging me, is there any way to see the widgets in a seperate view in qt creator? If I have 12 filters then there will be 12 different sets of widgets all stacks on top of one another.

Comment: @Zypps987: I believe what you need is a layout. Could you tell me what are the widgets you are talking about?

Comment: Any of the input widgets and the display widgets.

http://i.imgur.com/iUFpVet.png here's a screenshot of what I have right now. When an item in the top right QComboBox is selected the corresponding qwidgets will be displayed in the area where the current horizontal trackbars are.